# Single DSL to generate different representations in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, json, rest

I like the idea of using a single DSL to generate different representations and for that purpose I'm currently using [Hypertemplate](https://github.com/caelum/hypertemplate) packed into [Restfulie](https://github.com/caelum/restfulie):

But seeing the low number of watchers and forks on these projects I feel being very off the common trend, so I probably miss something.

What is the common way to describe cross-format representations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better gem to do that is [rabl](http://github.com/nesquena/rabl)

Rabl support a lot of representation :

- JSON
- XML
- MessagePack
- BSON
- Plist